# Remap data according to ranking

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following:

```
d = {"a":3,"b":2,"c":3,"d":2,"e":2,"f":3,"g":4, "h":6}

m = {v: i+1 for i,v in enumerate(sorted(set(d.values()),reverse=True))}
r = {k:m[d[k]] for k in d}
```

where `r` is:

```
{'a': 3, 'd': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 3, 'g': 2, 'h': 1}
```

So "h" has the highest value, 6, in `d` so it is remapped to 1 in `r`. Then 'g' is ranked 2 since it has the next highest value, 4 in `d`.

My solution works fine but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ranker(d):
    ranks = sorted(set(d.values()),reverse=True)
    ranks = {r:i+1 for i,r in enumerate(ranks)}
    return {k: ranks[v] for k,v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

Python dicts don't keep order. If you want that you need an `OrderedDict`.

Use `Counter` to get the ranks. Then turn that into a list of tuples or into an `OrderedDict`.

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

d = {"a":3,"b":2,"c":3,"d":2,"e":2,"f":3,"g":4, "h":6}
c = Counter(d)

# if you want a list of tuples
ranked_list = [(pair[0],rank+1) for rank,pair in enumerate(c.most_common())]
# [('h', 1),('g', 2),('f', 3),('a', 4),('c', 5),('b', 6),('d', 7), ('e', 8)]

# if you want a dict:
ranked_dict = OrderedDict(ranked_list)
# OrderedDict([('h', 1),('g', 2),('f', 3),('a', 4),('c', 5),('b', 6),('d', 7), ('e', 8)])
```

Comment: thats nice as well - you can use `enumerate(iterable, startingvalue)` to start the enumeration at 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
d = {"a":3,"b":2,"c":3,"d":2,"e":2,"f":3,"g":4, "h":6}

# sort the dictionary items by -value, throw away old value and use the
# enumerate position starting at 1 instead - no backreferencing in the old
# dict needed here

k = {k:idx for idx,(k,_) in enumerate(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x:-x[1]),1)}

print(k)
```

Output:

```
{'h': 1, 'g': 2, 'a': 3, 'c': 4, 'f': 5, 'b': 6, 'd': 7, 'e': 8}
```